# How to use griddata from scipy.interpolate

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, interpolation, mayavi

I have a three-column (x-pixel, y-pixel, z-value) data with one million lines. The data is from an image and there are duplicated z-values. Now I need to make a surface plot. [This image](http://www.mathworks.cn/help/matlab/ref/griddata_ex1.png) is a perfect example. But now the  output image is null. Could someone check the code please?

```
import numpy as np
from enthought.mayavi import mlab
from scipy.interpolate import griddata
x,y,z = np.loadtxt('test.csv',delimiter=',',usecols=(0,1,2),unpack=True) 
xi,yi = np.mgrid[0:3000:3000j, 0:3000:3000j]
zi = griddata((x, y), z, (xi, yi),method='linear')
mlab.surf(xi,yi,zi)
mlab.show()
```

Comment: why `0:3000:3000j`? shouldn't it be `0:3000:1`

Comment: `0:3000:1` is equally nonsensical. Maybe `0:3000`?

Comment: The two ways are the same.Either of them makes zi null.

Comment: @psuedoDust - `mgrid` interprets a complex number passed in as a step as the _number_ of steps in the output array.  For example, `np.mgrid[:3:3j]` yields `[0, 1.5, 3]`, while `np.mgrid[:3]` would yield `[0, 1, 2]`.

Answer (score 5):

I can't check the code without having the data, but I suspect that the problem is that you are using the default `fill_value=nan` as a `griddata` argument, so if you have gridded points that extend beyond the space of the (x,y) points, there are NaNs in the grid, which mlab may not be able to handle (matplotlib doesn't easily).  Try setting `fill_value=0` or another suitable real number.